# What is the best way to propagate user entered calculations throughout the model?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I'm creating a table with months as columns and 70+ rows of data. Each cell is dynamically calculated based on the values of other cells and the user can enter/update the input. Some values are generated by calculating 10 or more values from other cells so it becomes a mess quickly.
What I did is created a lot of functions that do the calculations and return results, but I am wondering if there is a better solution. Is it possible to directly update the model and have it propagate the most recent calculations to all the cells?

I see Angular has (change) and (ngModelChange) which could possibly be used?

Any guidance is helpful, thank you!

Comment: Try exploring `ReactiveFormsModule` and related classes to have a better hold on your data. Link: https://angular.io/api/forms/ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: Thank you, will look into it more! :)